# Setting up git using Powershell script

Tags: git, powershell

Looking for some advice how can I download latest & install git & its dependencies on my machine using Powershell script. I have gone through [_](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/wiki/Silent-or-Unattended-Installation) but it seems its been deprecated.I am on windows and I can write the commands to download and install but not sure from where to download the installation file?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to use chocolatey to install packages as it provides a consistent interface for installing a vast variety of windows apps.

From Powershell (Ensure Get-ExecutionPolicy is at least RemoteSigned):

```
# install chocolatey
iwr https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1 | iex

#install git
choco install git
```